# Why, Where, and When to use reference pointers in filters/hooks?

Tags: actions, filters, references

Why, Where, and When to use reference pointers in filters/hooks? What are the potential cons of not using them when suggested or required? Just looking for a more detailed answer than the codex provides and maybe some real world applications of this.

For example: `add_filter('some_wp_filter', array(&$this, 'my_function_to_filter');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example you give is used when you're building a plugin/theme using a class.

In normal use, your `functions.php` file would just have:

```
function my_function_to_filter( $args ) {
    // ... function stuff here
    return $args;
}
add_filter('some_wp_filter', 'my_function_to_filter');
```

If you're using a class, though, things would look different.  You'd likely have a `my-class.php` file containing:

```
class My_Class {
    function my_function_to_filter( $args ) {
        // ... function stuff here
        return $args;
    }
    add_filter('some_wp_filter', array(&$this, 'my_function_to_filter'));
}
```

In this case, `&$this` is passing in a reference to the class so that the filter called is the `my_function_to_filter` function in the current class.  You can also do this with static methods if you want to keep your filter calls all in the same place.

So in `my-class.php` you'd have:

```
class My_Class {
    static function my_function_to_filter( $args ) {
        // ... function stuff here
        return $args;
    }
}
```

And in `functions.php` or your core plugin file you'd have:

```
add_filter('some_wp_filter', array('My_Class', 'my_function_to_filter'));
```

Comment: Is this really required? Shouldn't PHP always pass a reference to that function anyway?

Comment: This is how the filter/action system handles naming collisions. If you pass the class containing the function, you can have several classes defining `function my_finction_to_filter(){}` without any conflicts. Remember, you're passing a ref to the *class* so that it's stored in the action/filter's lookup table for later when WP calls `apply_filters()`/`do_action()`.

Comment: Just a side note: Since PHP5 the default behavior is to pass objects by reference. The `&` before the `$this` reference is only required for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @Roman - Good point. A lot of us merely add the `&` out of force of habit. But if you're specifying `static` for functions, you're already in PHP5 territory ...